# How can I add Embed message from an array discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I make a Bot About Truth and Dare. When I type +t it sends one of the truths I added. Now I want to send the truth or dares embed Like this
[embed truths or dares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIuPK.png)

so How can I do this? Remember I will reply to random data from the array with embed
my Code

```
// Array of possible truth replies
const t = [
    "If you could be invisible, what is the first thing you would do?", 
    "What's the strangest dream you've ever had?",
    "What are the top three things you look for in a boyfriend/girlfriend?",
    "What is your worst habit?",
    "How many stuffed animals do you own?",
    "What is your biggest insecurity?"
];

// Array of possible dare replies
const d = [
    "Do a free-style rap for the next minute.",
    "Let another person post a status on your behalf.",
    "Hand over your phone to another player who can send a single text saying anything they want to anyone they want.",
    "Let the other players go through your phone for one minute.",
    "Smell another player's armpit",
    "Smell another player's barefoot.",
    "Tell everyone your honest opinion of the person who sent this command."
];

// Handle all commands here
client.on('message', message => {

    // Don't reply to itself
    if (message.author.id === client.user.id) return;

    // If there is no + (prefix) at the beginning of the message, exit function
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    // Remove the prefix from the message -> our command
    const command = message.content.substring(prefix.length);

    // Match the command
    if (command === "t") { // Truth
        const truth = t[Math.floor(Math.random() * t.length)];
        message.channel.send(truth);
    } else if (command === "d") { // Dare
        const dare = d[Math.floor(Math.random() * d.length)];
        message.channel.send(dare);
    } else if (command === "help") { // Help

        const help = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#72dfa3')
            .setTitle(`Truth Or Dare`)
            .addFields(
                { name: '``+help``', value: 'For help' },
                { name: '``+t``', value: 'For Truth' },
                { name: '``+d``', value: 'For Your Dare' },
                { name: '``Created By``', value: 'AlpHa Coder [Labib Khan]' },
            )
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(`${message.author.username}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL());

        message.channel.send(help);

    } else { // No match found, invalid command
        message.channel.send("Invalid command, type `+help` for help.");
    }

});
```

Comment: People can get easily demotivated when they try to help you, but you don't provide any feedback ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/68727958/9776840

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i add Error Message in Discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68727626/how-can-i-add-error-message-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well You just need to use embeds like in the help command.

Here the code:

```js
if (command === "t") { // Truth
    const truth = t[Math.floor(Math.random() * t.length)];
    message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Truth")
        .setDescription(truth));
} else if (command === "d") { // Dare
    const dare = d[Math.floor(Math.random() * d.length)];
    message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Dare")
        .setDescription(dare));
}
```